# ingredient based search for multiple inputs

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 3 tables: recipes, ingredients and relation.When the user enters multiple ingredients, I need to return the appropriate recipe containing those ingredients. I have written a PHP code that finds the iid of the ingredients entered by user. But I cannot understand how to further write a query to find the recipes. Since there are multiple ingredients, which are uncertain at the time of coding, i cannot understand how to use an array in my php code.
For eg
I have 2 recipes TOAST and SANDWICH
I have bread and butter common for both, and vegetables for SANDWICH
How to write a query that returns just TOAST when I enter bread and butter as ingredients.

[image]

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['search_ingredients']))
{
  $q = urldecode(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST['ingredients']));
  $parameter = explode (" ",$q);
  $var = 0;
//print_r($parameter);

  foreach($parameter as $x)
  {
    //echo $x;
    $sql = "SELECT rname from recipes not in (select distinct rid from relations where iid not ib(SELECT  iid FROM  ingredients WHERE iname='".$x."'))";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or exit('{"Data":null,"Message":null,"Code":500}');
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row['iid'];
    $arr_id[$var] = $row['iid'];
    //echo $arr_id[$var];
    $var++;
  }
```

Comment: I wonder if I will ever see a question on Stack Overflow from someone using parametrized queries :-(

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:**
You have IDs of two ingridients: 1, 2 (bread, butter)

The main idea is to find recipies that NOT fit your conditions and then select OTHER recipies.

So query will be something like that:

`` SELECT DISTINCT `rid` FROM `relations` WHERE `rid` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `rid` FROM `relations` WHERE `iid` NOT IN (1,2)
); ``

Inner query will return recipies that have ingridients except bread and butter, and the outer query then will selects all other recipies.

So it will returns "1" which is recipe ID of toast.

Comment: @SeRRglOthank you very much. I had actually got the sql query but I didnt know how to insert all the values of array in the query. But I got it using implode().

Comment: @Anu.Manoj Sorry, misunderstand question. You should not use implode to insert data into query directly because it is not safe. You should use parametrized queries. You can look to official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php which have good examples.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Il surely look into it.